# First X items in foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, rss

This may well be a silly question to many, but I've fried my brain sorting out various things today and can't think where to start. Sorry in advance.

I'm pulling in an RSS feed from a Wordpress site to another webpage. That is working and displaying a list of all the posts.

I'm using this code (from another post I made):

```
function getFeed($feed_url) {

$content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);

echo "<ul>";

foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
    echo "<li><a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->title . "</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
}
getFeed("http://your-wordpress-site/feed/");
```

I would however like to only show the first 8 entries.

Would I need to use something other than a foreach loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just keep a counter, then use `break` to exit the loop when you hit the maximum value you want.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
    echo "<li><a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->title . "</a></li>";
    $i++;
    if ($i >= 8){
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. My brain could not get there today... :-)

Comment: It might be a little 'cleaner' to use the $key, as you can define it as the index for each item in the loop. Something like this: `foreach($array as $key=>$value)` and then make a statement for the first x items, e.g.: `if($key > 8)` statement..